# Arithmetic operator in java

Tags: java

I have encountered strange arithmetic operations and here is the code:

```
    int i = 9 + + 8 - - 11 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;

    System.out.println(i);
```

It works without compilation error and gives the output 70, I have tried to google but did not find the correct explanations. Please pardon me I am new to Java.

Comment: why should this be a strange expression? it´s just a simply mathematic equation, where substracting a negativ value from a value will add it to the value

Comment: you don't know  - -=+ and + + =+ ?

Comment: @Rustam, yes I know but I was not aware that this syntax is valid in Java. As I said I am new to java so I find it difficult to understand

Comment: It's not about java it's basic maths. Is't it?

Comment: @Supreet it is the same as if the equation would say `x = y - z` where z is a negativ value, just with constant values.

Comment: @Rustam, it may not be just math. It has a lot to do with java syntax. The same might not work in all the other languages.

Comment: @Ramsharan check the OP statement. it's not `--` its  `- - ` space has meaning

Comment: @Ramsharan, that is the reason I got confused, `--` I know it is Decrement operator, but in this expression it is space `- -`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int i = 9 + + 8 - - 11 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = 9 + (+8) - (-11) + (+13) - (-14) + (+15);
```

which is equivalent to

```
int i = 9 + 8 + 11 + 13 + 14 + 15;
```

which is equal to 70

Comment: @Supreet Yes, subtracting a negative number `(x - (-3))` is the same as adding the absolute value of that number `(x + 3)`.

Answer (score 2):

`9+ +8` is equivalent to `9+(+8)` and

`8- -11` is equivalent to `8-(-11)`

so `9 + + 8 - - 11 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15` is equivalent to `9+(+8)-(-11)+(+13)-(-14)+(+15)`

which is equivalent to `9+8+11+13+14+15` = `70`

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is mathematical arithmetic operation and the same applies in Java:

`- - = +`

`+ + = +`

`int i = 9 + 8 + 11 + 13 + 14 + 15;`

so it is `70`